# Копирование компонента

Tags: vue.js

Как правильно скопировать часть компонента vue в другой компонент vue?

Скопировал часть одного компонента в другой компонент и получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Как я понимаю, то проблема возникает в `Store.state`

Как правильно перенести часть одного компонента в другой компонент?

Answer (score 0):

Видимо компонент, ожидает какого то поведения от vuex. Так что скорее да, проблема в STORE. Уточните код, компонента, и вашего Store.State. Или просто покапайтесь в store.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы включить части компонента в другой, лучше иметь 3 компонента: 2 компонента и один общий, который вы импортируете в другие.

Но для ситуации с `store`, документация vuex [напоминает](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html), что использование `Store.state` - плохая идея:

> «Однако этот шаблон заставляет компонент полагаться на одноэлементное
>   глобальное хранилище. При использовании системы модулей требуется
>   импортировать хранилище в каждый компонент, который использует
>   состояние хранилища, а также требует проверки при проверке компонента»

Сделать store доступным везде можно так :

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // provide the store using the "store" option.
  // this will inject the store instance to all child components.
  store,
  components: { Counter },
  template: `
    <div class="app">
      <counter></counter>
    </div>
  `
})"
```

А затем получить к нему доступ через: `this.$store.state`
Кстати, вот ещё возможно полезная [ссылка](https://flaviocopes.com/vue-import-component/) по импорту